# Problem importing dsplot library in Pycharm

Tags: python, windows, pycharm

I am exploring tree plots with the following library and code:

```
from dsplot.graph import Graph

graph = Graph(
    {0: [1, 4, 5], 1: [3, 4], 2: [1], 3: [2, 4], 4: [], 5: []}, directed=True
)
graph.plot()
```

When I run the code, I get the following error:

```
from dsplot.graph import Graph
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dsplot'
```

I have tried pip installing the `dsplot` library with this command on the PyCharm terminal:

```
pip install dsplot
```

But this then causes another error:

```
    Collecting dsplot
  Using cached dsplot-0.9.0-py3-none-any.whl (8.8 kB)
Collecting pygraphviz<2.0,>=1.7
  Using cached pygraphviz-1.12.tar.gz (104 kB)
  ERROR: Error [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified while executing command pip subprocess to install build dependencies
  Installing build dependencies ... error
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified
```

What is the reason for this problem installing the library and how can I resolve it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you have not installed `pygraphviz`.

**Install `pygraphviz`**

Try downloading it from their [official website](https://graphviz.org/download/) and make sure its added to your path by clicking "Add Graphviz to the System PATH for the current user". In your terminal, run `dot -V` and if it outputs your version of `pygraphviz`, you should be all set to run `pip install dsplot`.

**If `dot -V` does not return the Version:**

Make sure you checked this box during installation:

[image]

If you checked the box and it is still not in your PATH:

1. Find where Graphviz is installed; it is likely in "C:\Program Files\Graphviz" but is dependent on installation and OS. Click on this directory, and right click on "bin" to copy the path.
2. Open Start Search, type "env", and select "Edit the system environment variables".
3. Click "Environment Variables" in System Properties
4. Find "Path Variables" under "System Variables" and select "Edit"
5. Click "New"
6. Paste in the path of Graphviz, which is likely something like C:\Program Files\Graphviz\bin
7. Click "Ok" on all open windows to apply the changes

After adding `Graphviz` to your path, open a terminal and once again try `dot -V`. If that returns the version, then you should be able to run `pip install dsplot`.

Answer (score 0):

### Windows

Installing Graphviz and PyGraphviz on Windows can be tricky, as explained in [their installation documentation](https://pygraphviz.github.io/documentation/stable/install.html#:%7E:text=Historically%2C%20installing%20Graphviz%20and%20PyGraphviz%20on%20Windows%20has%20been%20challenging).  Specifically, I was getting the following error when trying to install dsplot:

> pygraphviz/graphviz_wrap.c(3020): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'graphviz/cgraph.h': No such file or directory

To fix the issue, I did the following:

1. First, I manually downloaded and installed the .exe from [here](https://graphviz.org/download/#:%7E:text=graphviz%2D9.0.0%20(64%2Dbit)%20EXE%20installer).
2. Then, I ran the following in Command Prompt to install pygraphviz:

   ```
   pip install --use-pep517 --config-settings="--global-option=build_ext" --config-settings="--global-option=-IC:\Program Files\Graphviz\include" --config-settings="--global-option=-LC:\Program Files\Graphviz\lib" pygraphviz
   ```
3. Then, I was able to successfully install dsplot using:

   ```
   pip install dsplot
   ```

I think step 2 gets around the error because the missing file `cgraph.h` is located in `C:\Program Files\Graphviz\include\graphviz` after you run the manual installation in step 1.

### Mac

I also had the same error on my mac, but in that case I was able to avoid it by updating pip to the latest version by running the following in Terminal:

```
python -m pip install --upgrade pip
```